# How to use where condition for a column which contains comma delimited values using Hibernate and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Used arraylist in where clause for a column as below with **Hibernate** and **MYSQL**.

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("name1");
list.add("name2");
list.add("name3");

String query= "from TEST where name in (:names)";
Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
q.setParameterList("names", list);
```

But need to implement the same where condition for a column which is comma delimited values.
All the records has to be shown if any value from this column presents in arraylist

**Table Structure**

```
ID   NAME
----------
1   name1,name2,name3
2   name1
3   name2,name3
4   name5,name8
5   name3,name6
```

**Expected result:**

records with id **1,2,3,5** has to be displayed.

**Problem Statement:**
I want to use Hibernate criteria with restrictions and i have arraylist to use in where clause and we can't use 
**Restrictions.in("name",list);** 
because this name column contains comma delimited values and we need to check if any of element from arraylist is a part of data in this column.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing that DB structure would be my advice.

However, if you need a solution right now, I would suggest you use `like` SQL sentence. It will check if the given string is contained in the results.

Here you have a link on the matter so that you can see how it works: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Your SQL would turn into something like this:

```
from TEST where name like (:names)
```

Comment: can we use using criteria as below
**Restrictions.like("NAME",list);**

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Is it supposed to be a question?

Comment: i want to use Hibernate criteria with restrictions and i have arraylist to use in where clause and we can't use **Restrictions.in("name",list);** because this **name** column contains comma delimited values and we need to check if any of element from arraylist is a part of data in this column. Hope am clear and please let me know if you need more information